# Why do I need SSH authorisation to clone an openly-available Git repo?

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket

On BitBucket and GitHub, you cannot clone a public repo via the Git/SSH protocol unless your SSH key is authorised [1]. You can clone them via HTTPS - you just wont' have push access. Why is this? Couldn't the server just record "a user with SSH key X cloned this repo but does not have push access"?

Is this a limitation of Git+SSH, a limitation of BitBucket's specific setup, or a totally valid design decision?

[1] Apologies if I'm mistaken, but I can't see a way to change this via BitBucket's web interface.

Comment: ssh is an obvious target for attacks, so it would be imprudent to allow anonymous ssh access. Whereas anonymous HTTP is the norm.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to clone a Git repository over SSH without even *having* an SSH key.

I suspect that you're confusing the *server* SSH key with your own. The first time you connect to any machine over SSH you will be greeted [with a message like this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-4-test-everything-out):

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
# RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
# Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

This is to verify that you have connected to the correct *server*, and ensure that no [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) is going on. It has very little to do with what GitHub and/or Bitbucket allow or with Git; it's an important part part of the SSH security model.

You should verify that the fingerprint matches the [one published by GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints) one time, and then type `yes`. Your machine will remember that the fingerprint has been accepted for future transastions.

Answer (score 0):

You client side can have more than one SSH key. This is the case, for example, when you generate different private/public keys to access different servers.

And moreover, (even if seldom), the same SSH key can be shared among different clients.

Answer (score 0):

SSH was really created as a device of letting remote users log in to the system and serving Git repos over it (using virtualized users) is really sort of a hack (however clever it be).

In theory, it might be possible to configure the SSH server, the underlying system and whatever serves Git behind SSH (services like the one you mentioned certainly do not serve Git directly over SSH and have a mediating system in the spirit of `gitolite`) but I think people seldom need this.  Why?  Because if you're okay with making a read access of the repository to anyone, you will not need any authentication and might just serve it using the native Git wire protocol (`git://` in the URIs) or HTTP[S].

Note that Git supports different URLs for pushing and fetching for the same remote, so you can do something like this:

```
git clone https://git-hoster.example.com/user/repo.git
cd repo
git remote set-url --push origin ssh://git@git-hoster.example.com/user/repo.git
```

Now fetches will use the HTTPS protocol and pushes will go through SSH and will require an authorized private key.